# Сборка проекта C++

Tags: c++

Начал изучать C++, возникли вопросы по библиотекам времени исполнения. Использую vs2012

1. Зачем нужны эти библиотеки и какие функции содержатся в них?
2. Возможно ли собрать проект вообще без них?
3. Можно ли указать компоновщику чтобы он связывал екзешник с msvcrt а не с mscr110?

Comment: Чистый C++ используете, или какой-нибудь C++\CLI ?

Comment: С без всяких  cli .net

Comment: На первый вопрос ответит [вот эта](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.100).aspx) статья

Comment: Кстати, что Вас подтолкнуло задать этот вопрос ? Какие-то ошибки ? Вроде _someone method already defined in .._ ?

Comment: Нет.просто хочу понять как работает код в ОС когда его запускают

Comment: Ну вот Вы прочтете статью, которую я Вам скинул, и, как мне кажется, далее сами поймете, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Спасибо большое.Кажется понял что они нужны для выделения памяти и т.д но если я создаю hello world какой нибудь ,эти библиотеки в принципе не нужны ,нет?

Comment: Не уверен - слишком важными вещами они занимаются. Вот [тут](http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623) про это не плохо написано.

Comment: Спасибо  за ссылки

Comment: Не за что, рад был помочь !

Answer (score 2):

1. Библиотеки нужны для работы программы. В них содержатся различные функции, которые вы можете использовать в своих программах. В стандартных библиотеках, поставляемых с компиляторами - код функций *стандартной библиотеки*, вместе с кодом поддержки.
2. Теоретически можно. Только что будет уметь такой код? В нем нельзя будет использовать никакого ввода, вывода, да даже параметры командной строки или функции операционной системы (как вы к ним обратитесь?) Тот же ваш Hello потянет за собой целую библиотеку - надо же не просто вывести слово, а открыть файловый поток, обработать ошибки etc etc...

К пункту второму - воспоминания молодости, как я во времена Borland C++ 3.1 попробовал кастрировать startup-код, так что пустая программа у меня была под сотню байт, и дописал свою микробиблиотечку - ввода-вывода через DOS/BIOS, свой микроменеджер памяти, работа с файлами через DOS. Программы выходили реально мизерного размера, как на ассемблере писанные. Чем они, по сути, и являлись. Но все нужно было писать самому :)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю эту строчку: "It sets up the module entry point, such as preparing argc/argv for console applications". [Сам документ](http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-the-visual-c-runtime-library/184416623). Т.е. заюзал main - готовься к тому, что будут заюзаны runtime libraries ?

Comment: Да, конечно. Это код, который разбирает командную строку (создает параметры для `main`), открывает стандартные файлы, инициализирует менеджер памяти... - вобщем, подготавливает все для работы `main`. Я и начинал в своем эксперименте - *попробовал кастрировать startup-код* - именно с него. Формально, кстати, он может библиотеки и не подтягивать - это уж как разработчики подсуетились...

Comment: Понял, спасибо !